# how can redirect sign in and sign out link front-end page rather then wp-login .php in comment form in wordpress

Tags: login

I want to redirect the signin and signout link from comment form in Wordpress.

I am using a plugin to register users from the front-end; there I have two pages: sign-in and register. When someone registers from this page and logs in from this page, then its working fine.

But when someone is going to give a comment to a post and is not logged in, then a link shows directing the user to login. Upon clicking this link it goes to `wp-login.php`, but I want to redirect this link to my sign-in page and after sign in the sign out link should go to this page as well.

How can I do this?

Comment: hi am add this function in my function.php but it give the error at wp-login.php Warning: Missing argument 2 for my_login_redirect() in /var/www/html/universis/dev/wp-content/themes/uniersis/functions.php on line 672 Warning: Missing argument 3 for my_login_redirect() in /var/www/html/universis/dev/wp-content/themes/uniersis/functions.php on line 672   
actually i want to edit wp-includes/comment-template.php function namely comment_form. when i am click looged-in link shows at comment form its go to at my sign-in page not wp-login.php

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter [`login_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect) to redirect users to a page of your choice after login, and `logout_url` to redirect them after logging out.

An example would be the following:

```
function my_login_redirect( $url, $request, $user ){

     // Redirect non administrator users to a custom url.
     // Administrator gets redirected to default url 
     if( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) )
         return 'my-custom-url';
     else return $url;

}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect');
```

Comment: hi am add this function in my function.php but it give the error at wp-login.php Warning: Missing argument 2 for my_login_redirect() in /var/www/html/universis/dev/wp-content/themes/uniersis/functions.php on line 672

Warning: Missing argument 3 for my_login_redirect() in /var/www/html/universis/dev/wp-content/themes/uniersis/functions.php on line 672

Comment: actually i want to edit wp-includes/comment-template.php function namely comment_form.  when i am click looged-in link shows at comment form its go to at my sign-in page not wp-login.php

Comment: Uhm… alright, what's your signin page?